# Creating Lucene Index On SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, solr, lucene.net, solrnet

I am creating a custom web application in C# .NET and I have a completely custom built database schema. I need a search engine application which is comprehensive enough to search the entire database I am using. We have decided to use Lucene .NET and probably Solr on top. I would like some help though as I'm a beginner.

**Firstly, how do I go about creating a Lucene .NET index using C# on a SQL Server 05 or 08 database?? If anyone can help me by explaining the steps involved, where to reference Lucene .NET files from etc. any help would be much appreciated.**

**Secondly, we are proposing using Solr on top to add additional functionality, but how do I go about doing this? What way does it run and what is required etc??** If using Solr on a Microsoft SQL Server box, must I use SolrNet over Solr?

Thanks in advance for all help received!

Comment: If you don't plan to use Solr, you might find this helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059/lucene-net-and-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

> use Lucene .NET and probably Solr on top

Solr doesn't run on top of Lucene.NET. It's a stand-alone Java Search server built on top of Java (original) Lucene.

The simplest way to import data from a relational database into Solr is using the [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler).

SolrNet is a client, a .net library that communicates with Solr via HTTP. I briefly explained how the interactions work in [this blog post](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/10/untangling-mess-solr-solrnet-nhibernate.html).