# How to Store strings to Optimize Searching

Tags: c#, sql-server, search, string-algorithm

I am having a table containing a column of type VARCHAR. I want to search strings inside the column according to user input query. I want to implement Approximate Searching. And my table contains Lacs of records. There are some ways I am thinking I can implement searching.

1. Load All records in C# and apply searching algorithm on it. (But it will consume too much memory.)
2. Fetch records individually or in some predefined batch size and apply searching algorithm on it. (But it will establish database connection rapidly, which may downgrade the performance.)

I am sure that, there will be some other mechanism to implement this functionality or some technique to store data so that i can search it faster.

Can anybody give me any better idea, to implement this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into full-text search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: If you write a database function you can use that function in your SQL. Nowadays most databases have languages able to code a fuzzy search.

Comment: @Tao: Why don't you make that comment into an answer? You'll most likely get some rep for it.

Comment: @LukeH: fair enough, I didn't want to take the time to write a proper answer, but I guess i accidentally "claimed" the answer in my comment.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed SQL Server, but I just realized this is not specified; @Coder, can you confirm / retag?

Comment: @Tao: yeah, I am trying to implement it in SQL server only. And thanks for the link posting. It is really interesting. I'll try to use it if it can do the thing....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) is one of the best ways to search. You can still store your string in the database, but build a Lucene index out of it and then use it to search.

Comment: Might be nice to indicate how one might go about it, this question seems to link to a tutorial/overview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059/lucene-net-and-sql-server/37173#37173

Comment: @Tao: Thank for the reference Tao, really nice tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has built-in functionality to do exactly what you're looking to do, it's called Full-Text Search.

Overview from Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

The general concept is that you tell SQL Server what tables/columns contain searchable text, and it builds space-efficient and query efficient "full-text indexes"; these indexes are built asynchronously (so your updates/inserts are not slowed down), and since SQL Server 2005 they are stored with your database (eg in backups), so they're easily managed.

When you want to search, the query language is different from "normal" text matching.

Full-Text search is even available in the free "SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services" edition, so cost is no longer a concern.